# Wrong 1st argument type. Found: android.webkit.WebViewClient, required: android.app.Activity

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

When I tried to implement Chrome Custom Tabs using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` in `webViewClient()` I am getting the following error:

> Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'android.webkit.WebViewClient', required: 'android.app.Activity'

Here is my code - I am using this GitHub repository https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client.
The error is coming from my usage of the `this` keyword.

**I am in Fragment, not in Activity**

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build();
        CustomTabActivityHelper.openCustomTab(this, customTabsIntent, Uri.parse(url), new WebviewFallback());

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "This is a message displayed in a Toast" + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        toast.show();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: CustomTabActivityHelper is not found. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 5):

You are using `this` is within the context of an anonymous class (`new WebViewClient()`), so `this` is referring a type of `WebViewClient`.

Since you're using a fragment, you can replace `this` with `getActivity()`:

```
CustomTabActivityHelper.openCustomTab(getActivity(), customTabsIntent, Uri.parse(url), new WebviewFallback());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if i am inside a fragment, what should i use ?

Comment: `CustomTabActivityHelper.openCustomTab(getActivity().this, customTabsIntent, Uri.parse(url), new WebviewFallback());` It is showing error at this as ") expected" am i missing anything here?

Comment: You don't need `.this` after `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like "this" is your WebViewClient not your Activity.
If your shown code is in a Activity, try to use "YourActivity.this" to specify.

Hope it helped.

Comment: I am using inside a fragment, so what should i use ?

Comment: You can use [getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29) to get the activity of the fragment.

Comment: `CustomTabActivityHelper.openCustomTab(getActivity().this, customTabsIntent, Uri.parse(url), new WebviewFallback());`  It is showing error at this as ") expected" am i missing anything here?

Comment: Because you are in an anonymous class you need to call `YourFragment.this.getActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be depends on the android build version problem, the below code will work successfully on 2.3+ builds, check this out

```
ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
        String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.d("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code:" + errorCode + " - " + description);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // handle different requests for different type of files
            // this example handles downloads requests for .apk and .mp3 files
            // everything else the webview can handle normally
            if (url.endsWith(".apk")) {
                Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
                // Make a new request pointing to the .apk url
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
                // appears the same in Notification bar while downloading
                request.setDescription("Description for the DownloadManager Bar");
                request.setTitle("YourApp.apk");
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                }
                // save the file in the "Downloads" folder of SDCARD
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "SmartPigs.apk");
                // get download service and enqueue file
                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                manager.enqueue(request);
            }
            else if(url.endsWith(".mp3")) {
                // if the link points to an .mp3 resource do something else
            }
            // if there is a link to anything else than .apk or .mp3 load the URL in the webview
            else view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;                
    }
});
```